# Emails from our domain being blocked

Tags: email, smtp

We have our emails running through Google Apps. One of our staff members working from Taiwan is experiencing many if not all of her attempts to send emails to clients in Taiwan are not getting received.

This seems to be unique to taiwan emails only, as sending email to other addresses internationally works without issues.

What makes the problem more bizzare is that some gmail.com address do receive the email, and some don't. And it isn't in their spam folder either.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to resolve this issue? Or what questions I need to answer to help isolate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As your emails are running through Google Apps, your domains mail server is at google. When you send a mail from your domain to any google account, the email is actually send between google servers. And if you face issue with this you need to contact google support team with the details.

Regards,
Ajo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem may be related to invalid PTR records after checking http://www.spamcannibal.org. I've tried this first. Our web server emails have also sometimes gotten blocked. So let's see.